# display block com css no mouseover

Tags: css, css3

Em `CSS` tem jeito de ao passar o mouse em um elemento, fazer `display: block` em outro como se faz em `JS`?

O objeto é que eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<ul class="menuAdmin centralisado">
    <li>
        <label>Cadastros</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?inserir&cliente">Clientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="?inserir&produto">Produtos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Listagens</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?listar&clientes">Clientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="?listar&pedidos">Pedidos</a></li>
            <li><a href="?listar&produtos">Podutos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Preciso fazer que ao passar o mouse por exemplo no label Listagens, a ul abaixo dele, que estará com `diplay: none`, se torne `display: block`

Comment: existe o `:hover` com o operador `+`. ex: `label:hover + ul`, mas da uma olhada no link que o @sam mencionou

Comment: desculpe mas não consegui encontrar nas respostas aonde está o mouseover e a colocação do display:block no elemento irmão

Comment: assim: ul.menuAdmin li label:hovet + ul {
 display: block;
}

?

Comment: sim, mas é `:hover` e não `:hovet`

Comment: eu sei, acontece. kkk, valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer da maneira abaixo:

```
ul.menuAdmin > li > ul {
   display: none;
}
ul.menuAdmin > li:hover > ul {
    display: block
}
```

Html

```
<ul class="menuAdmin centralisado">
    <li>
        <label>Cadastros</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?inserir&cliente">Clientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="?inserir&produto">Produtos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Listagens</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?listar&clientes">Clientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="?listar&pedidos">Pedidos</a></li>
            <li><a href="?listar&produtos">Podutos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era isso mesmo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Em JavaScript o código ficaria assim.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
  

  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <ul class="menuAdmin centralisado">
    <li>
        <label>Cadastros</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?inserir&cliente">Clientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="?inserir&produto">Produtos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Listagens</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?listar&clientes">Clientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="?listar&pedidos">Pedidos</a></li>
            <li><a href="?listar&produtos">Podutos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


<script>

var Listagens = window.document.getElementsByTagName("label")[1];
var ListaUl = window.document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1];
Listagens.addEventListener("mouseover", ListagensLista);

function ListagensLista() {
  ListaUl.style.display = "block";
  console.log("E sou bloco");
}

</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```